# Is it possible to create image data and save to a file from a script

Tags: scripting, python, texturing, image

I'm currently trying to extract textures from a binary file, and ideally I'd like to save each texture to a file or embed in the `.blend` file. However, before saving an image, I need to be able to create an image in memory from an array of pixel data.

The PIL library contains the kinds of functions I need to use, but it is not included with Blender. Is there anything similar to PIL in Blender? bpy.ops.image seems to be close to what I need, but lacks necessary pixel set/manipulation functions.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes its possible, heres an example

```
size = 640, 480

import bpy
# blank image
image = bpy.data.images.new("MyImage", width=size[0], height=size[1])

## For white image
# pixels = [1.0] * (4 * size[0] * size[1])

pixels = [None] * size[0] * size[1]
for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        # assign RGBA to something useful
        r = x / size[0]
        g = y / size[1]
        b = (1 - r) * g
        a = 1.0

        pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]

# flatten list
pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]

# assign pixels
image.pixels = pixels

# write image
image.filepath_raw = "/tmp/temp.png"
image.file_format = 'PNG'
image.save()
```

[image: output of script]

Comment: With this technic is it possible to save the image with RGBA I made some test but I can't find how to do it directly with python?

Comment: Do you mean doing this from regular Python? (which would work outside of Blender for example)

Comment: Nop inside of blender, I find the answer by myself. I can use image.save_render(...) instead of image.save() and it will take the render parameter

Comment: If you want to save PNG images without using Blender's API, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image/19174800#19174800

Comment: A [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253642/60486) was asked what is `chan` for in the line `pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]` - the line is an equivalent to `pixels = [] \n for chan in px: \n\t for px in pixels: \n\t\t pixels.append(px)` where `\n` and `\t` mean a newline and a tab.

Comment: If I have an array of pixels, can I copy data directly instead of running an expensive loop in python?

Comment: @user877329 this should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

And this is if we are using Sverchok Add-On and nodes in Sverchok. I am translating IdeasMan42 example. Neat.

Comment: If that's so neat, can you post a high-res image of your tree? Hard to see what you are doing here...

Comment: Sorry low resolution image. The last node is Texture Viewer. Everything else is Map Range and some Math node. The green node is Plane. Give it a try  :)

Comment: GIST: b6223f0152a98d88bd8a130562419c2d

Comment: Gist as real url: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6223f0152a98d88bd8a130562419c2d