# Capture a partial screenshot in the BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I am looking for a way to capture just a portion of the screen in the game engine. I was using the built-in `render.makeScreenshot(path)`, which only captures a full-screen PNG.

I am exploring the following approach but have no idea how to save the list data into an image format. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bgl import *
def captureCropped(posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY):
        buf = Buffer(GL_BYTE, [sizeX,sizeY,3])
        glReadPixels(posX,posY,sizeX,sizeY,GL_RGB,GL_BYTE,buf)
        ... #now what do I do with buf?
```

Comment: Using this answer, you should be able to write an image: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script/652#652

Comment: I want to avoid using bpy if possible. My understanding is that it is not (or should not be) available in the game engine/blenderplayer.

Comment: in that case Im not sure how you would do this besides writing the raw data directly, which - I should add, is not as hard as you might expect - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image/19174800#19174800

Comment: Could you answer this with the patch you wrote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to uses [plain Python to write out the PNG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image/19174800#19174800).

Another solution is to extend `render.makescreenshot(filename)` to accept additional optional argument in the form of `render.makescreenshot(filename, x, y, width, height)`
The work-in-progress patch is here:
http://www.pasteall.org/47215/diff

Note: The patch currently does not work correctly in Blender, it only works in BlenderPlayer.