# Can a python script open a blank image, draw with opengl commands and then save file to disc?

Tags: python, image, opengl

I want to use object vertex position data to draw 2D images using python

Comment: do you want to use the uv/editor?  please add some aditional information and search results

Comment: We can [create and edit images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/643/935), we can use [bgl](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bgl.html) to draw in the 3d view, I'm not sure if you can use bgl on an image.

Comment: I have built a rigid body brush with bristle spreading. I have stored locations of bristles that touch the paper plane in arrays. I want to simply plot and connect with lines using a python script to a blank image. Maybe grease pencil rendered could work.