# Create empty texture and modify pixel contents from Python

Tags: python, texturing

I have data in a numpy array that includes coordinates and colors, from a RGB point cloud. I have managed to create a grid which fairly accurately captures the geometry of my data, but I am having trouble creating a matching texture to apply the colors to the object. Ideally I would like to create an empty image texture and then set the individual pixel values.

I've checked the API documentation and google and haven't found much.

I'm aware of the ply import extension for blender, but I don't have my point cloud data in that format.

If I have to do any UV mapping to make this work, I'm happy to do that manually for now.

So, how can I create a texture (with given dimensions) with python in blender, and set the pixel values?

Comment: Have a look to this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script

Comment: I hadn't thought of just making the image file myself. Thanks.