# Can I get the computed shader's colors at specific points?

Tags: python, particles, shaders, animation-nodes

I have a mesh with a shader on it, as well as a particle system. The particles are emitted for only one frame, from the surface of the mesh, and are set to render None (I just want the 3d positions of the particles)

Is there any way (shader, animation nodes, python script) to get the rendered color of the mesh at the particles' positions? I can get the 3d positions via animation nodes, and can convert those to UV coordinates from the camera's POV, but I want the rendered image's pixel color at those coordinates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to write UV positions as pixels with python, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script