# How to create an image in Blender with python using Blender 3.6

Tags: python, scripting, color

I want to create images with a solid color in the project folder. But I get errors like this:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\01_Projects\01_Work_(RTG)_SSD\75_Autumn-credit\01-Work\03_BLENDER___Autumn-credit\Autumn-credit_2.blend\Text", line 38, in <module>
AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: Procedural Image, Image datablock, error setting Image.pixels
```

I have tried the following solution, but unfortunately it does not work for me:
[Is it possible to create image data and save to a file from a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script)

Comment: Hello, this script works, I'm pretty sure it's the way you are using it that makes it throw an error. Could you post a snippet of your code ?

Comment: yes it works. voted to close question.

Comment: hello, romanzham... please include that part of the code that is raising the error, and any info. about the context in which it is being executed that might be of any help to us.. otherwise this is very hard to diagnose.